# Sendgrid SMTP templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I've been reading over the sendgrid-ruby documentation and having a hard time. Looking at this page, how do I pass in a template to use?

I've tried passing various parameters into the mail method, but it's not been working.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/ruby.html

I just need enough to get started with templating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to pass variables via sendgrid template and display those variables inside view/html file?

```
class EmailMailer < SampleMailer      
  def send_data_emails(firstname, lastname)
    sendgrid_substitute  '-firstname-', firstname
    sendgrid_substitute  '-lastname-', lastname      
  end   
end
```

inside view file directly use these variables to display values

email_mailer.html.erb

> User First Name is: '-firstname-' User Last Name id: '-lastname-'

Comment: No I want to select the sendgrid template and use that! Currently all I can do is send text email.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ruby on Rails default ActionMailer methods for sending email through SendGrid.

In your `config/environment.rb` configure ActionMailer with your SendGrid settings.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'your_sendgrid_username',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_password',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Generate a new mailer with

`rails generate mailer <MailerName>`

and setup your mailer methods and views as usual.

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html
>
> https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

Comment: I'm specifically asking about how to use smtp templates, not how to send email.